# Listando informações com o select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Já abri uma questão dessa aqui e um usuário do site me ajudou, e sanou minhas dúvidas. Porém, ao tentar utilizar o código novamente que ele me apresentou, o mesmo esta apresentando erros. Ele me apresentou o código com Estados, e eu modifiquei para Bairros (código limpo pois as informações serão colocadas ainda.)

O código é o seguinte:

```
<script>
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
.module('appBairros', []);

  angular
.module('appBairros')
.controller('BairroController', BairroController);

  BairroController.$inject = [];

  function BairroController() {
var bairro = this;
bairro.opcoes = [];

iniciar();

function iniciar() {
  bairro.opcoes = [];
  bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Botafogo", informacoes: "Botafogo é um bairro     que começa com B"});
  bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Madureira", informacoes: "Madureira é um bairro     que começa com M"});

  bairro.seleciona = bairro.opcoes[0];
}
  }
    })();
```

```
<div ng-app="appBairros">
<div ng-controller="BairroController as bairro">
<label class="bairros">Selecione o Bairro para exibir as informações que             deseja.</label>
<select ng-options="opcao.nome for opcao in bairro.opcoes" ng-model="bairo.selecionado"></select>

<br>
<br>

{{bairro.selecionado.informacoes}}
```

Ele deveria apresentar assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando eu executo o meu código, ele apresenta dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

seu erro esta dentro da `function iniciar()` em `bairro.seleciona = bairro.opcoes[0];` deve ser `bairro.selecionado = bairro.opcoes[0];`
e tambem alterar `ng-model="bairo.selecionado"` para `ng-model="bairro.selecionado"` sendo `bairro` e não `bairo`

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('appBairros', []);

    angular
  .module('appBairros')
  .controller('BairroController', BairroController);

  BairroController.$inject = [];

  function BairroController() {
    var bairro = this;
    bairro.opcoes = [];

    iniciar();

    function iniciar() {
      bairro.opcoes = [];
      bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Botafogo", informacoes: "Botafogo é um bairro     que começa com B"});
      bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Madureira", informacoes: "Madureira é um bairro     que começa com M"});

      bairro.seleciona = bairro.opcoes[0];
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appBairros">
<div ng-controller="BairroController as bairro">
<label class="bairros">Selecione o Bairro para exibir as informações que             deseja.</label>
<select ng-options="opcao.nome for opcao in bairro.opcoes" ng-model="bairro.selecionado"></select>

<br>
<br>

{{bairro.selecionado.informacoes}}
```

Comment: Fiz essa correção e ainda não alterou na execução. Continua executando sem apresentar as opções.

Comment: confere sua digitacao, na sua model, voce esta usando bairo com 1 R .. e deveria usar bairro com 2 R

Answer (score 1):

Dois pequenos erros de digitação.

- No *controller*, onde se lê `bairro.seleciona = bairro.opcoes[0];`
  deve-se ler `bairro.selecionado = bairro.opcoes[0];`
- Na *view*, onde se lê `ng-model="bairo.selecionado"` deve-se ler `ng-model="bairro.selecionado"`

Com estas duas correções o código funciona, como se pode ver na versão abaixo:

```js
angular.module('appBairros', []);

angular.module('appBairros').controller('BairroController', BairroController);

BairroController.$inject = [];

function BairroController() {
var bairro = this;
bairro.opcoes = [];

iniciar();

function iniciar() {
bairro.opcoes = [];
bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Botafogo", informacoes: "Botafogo é um bairro     que começa com B"});
bairro.opcoes.push({nome: "Madureira", informacoes: "Madureira é um bairro     que começa com M"});

bairro.selecionado = bairro.opcoes[0];
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appBairros">
<div ng-controller="BairroController as bairro">
<label class="bairros">Selecione o Bairro para exibir as informações que             deseja.</label>
<select ng-options="opcao.nome for opcao in bairro.opcoes" ng-model="bairro.selecionado"></select>

<br>
<br>

{{bairro.selecionado.informacoes}}
```

Comment: Corrigi os erros observados e ainda sim quando executo não aparece as opções

Comment: @InezBoldrin o código funciona quando você clica no botão Executar acima?

Comment: Funciona sim. Funciona do jeito que deveria funcionar pra mim também.
Inclusive já peguei o código que está corrigido e substitui pelo que está no meu arquivo e continua sem apresentar as opções.

Comment: @InezBoldrin então seu erro pode estar sendo causado por algum outro aspecto da sua aplicação. O console mostra algum erro?

Comment: Só esses dois: **Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at especialidade.html:107
    at especialidade.html:130**

Comment: Ah, me parece que você não está carregando a biblioteca do Angular. Inclua a seguinte linha no início do seu HTML : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>` (ou a versão desejada.)

Comment: Eu tenho essa biblioteca aqui arquivo: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"> </script>`. Substitui essa pela que você me mostrou, e ainda nada.

Comment: A URL que você está utilizando no seu código inclui o caracter `&zwnj;` (zero-width non-joiner). Substitua a linha original toda pelo que enviei.